# how to create a Mock database and add data in mock db for integration testing using postgres db and java

Tags: java, testing, integration

I want to perform the Integration test for which I want to create a test DB and add some data.
how should I point to the test DB while doing an integration test?

Thanks for Help......

Answer (score 2):

You can use [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) for achieving this. You can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_i61qTg510) to get an idea about this and how to configure it in your spring boot application

For your spring integration test create a configuration like as shown below

**AbstractIT.java**

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE) // don't replace our DB with an in-memory one
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AbstractIT.DockerPostgresDataSourceInitializer.class)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public abstract class AbstractIT {

    private static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresDBContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:9.6")
            .withUrlParam("TC_DAEMON", "true")
            .withFileSystemBind("docker/db", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d", BindMode.READ_WRITE);

    static {
        postgresDBContainer.start();
    }

    public static class DockerPostgresDataSourceInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            Assertions.assertNotNull(applicationContext);
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(
                    applicationContext,
                    "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true",
                    "spring.datasource.driver-class-name="+postgresDBContainer.getDriverClassName(),
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + postgresDBContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + postgresDBContainer.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + postgresDBContainer.getPassword()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can write your Integration test like as shown in the below sample example

**UserControllerIT.java**

```
class UserControllerIT extends AbstractIT {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    @DisplayName("Testing to get all the user details")
    void getAllUsersTest() {
        ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> response = this.template.exchange("/v1/users", GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<UserDTO>>() {
        });
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(response.getBody())
                .isNotEmpty()
                .hasSize(3)
                .extracting(UserDTO::getEmail).containsAnyOf("user1@some.com");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    @DisplayName("Testing for saving user details")
    void saveUsersTest() {
        ResponseEntity<Void> response = this.template.postForEntity("/v1/users", new HttpEntity<>(buildUserRequest()), Void.class);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        long usersCount = userRepository.count();
        assertThat(usersCount).isEqualTo(4);
    }

    @Test
    @Order(3)
    @DisplayName("Testing to deleting user details by id")
    void deleteUsersTest() {

        this.template.delete("/v1/users/{id}", singleParam("id", "21"));

        boolean userExists = userRepository.existsById(21L);
        assertThat(userExists).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    @Order(4)
    @DisplayName("Testing to finding user details by id")
    void findUserByIdTest() {
        ResponseEntity<UserDTO> response = this.template.getForEntity("/v1/users/{id}", UserDTO.class, singleParam("id", "22"));

        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);

        assertThat(response.getBody())
                .extracting(UserDTO::getEmail, UserDTO::getFirstName, UserDTO::getLastName)
                .containsExactly("user2@some.com", "John", "Duke");
    }

    private UserDTO buildUserRequest() {
        return UserDTO.builder()
                .email("user4@some.com")
                .lastName("Maria")
                .firstName("Fernandes")
                .build();
    }

    private Map<String, String> singleParam(String key, String value) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(key, value);
        return params;
    }
}
```

You can see the full running application under this Github Repo - https://github.com/nidhishkrishnan/stackoverflow/tree/master/employee-testcontainer